# Google Storage Cloud bucket attached with GCSFUSE but nor gsutil nor ftp allow me to upload files

Tags: google-cloud-storage, wowza, gcsfuse

I deployed an instance of Wowza Streaming Engine on Google Cloud thank Made a bucket in Google Cloud Storage and mounted it all with GCFUSE. My bucket connected with success and I can see in it and list but I can't write any file with *gsutil* nor with any FTP even with RSA Key. I also tried gcsfuse -o allow_other but nothing change. What am I doing wrong please help

Comment: What message it retrieves to you? Any error message? How do you see and list your bucket? with gsutil command?

Comment: I always am able to list the bucket content with command, gsutil ls and also with Ftp client. I can read it but I cannot write in it. I tried with sudo chmod but silently does not change anythink I think is a privile issue how do not know how to fix it and I am stuck.

Comment: Could you provide us with the error message you are getting?

Comment: Thank you for the support problem solved writing under home folder. Was a privilege issue.

Comment: Could you write your the solution for your issue as an answer? Thank you.

Comment: I just mounted with gfuse within my home directory where I had authorizations enough and it worked. I was trying to connect under usr/local but I had not enough privilege

Comment: Please add this comment as an answer so it's easier for others seeking the answer with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a permission issue. I think a possible solution is here {1} and here {2}.

{1}: https://serverfault.com/questions/750640/permission-errors-using-gcsfuse-as-nonroot-user-on-google-compute-instance

{2}: [Google Cloud Storage Buckets: Mounting in a Linux instance with Global Permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731266/google-cloud-storage-buckets-mounting-in-a-linux-instance-with-global-permissio?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Answer based on OP's comment:

It was permissions issue.

Mounted with gfuse within home directory with sufficient permissions and it worked.